# Swift: Substring based on a character

Tags: swift, substring, nsdate

I'm getting information from an API and one of the fields is a DateTime in this format:

2014-12-12T14:44:18.973

I would like to remove the "T" and anything after it so in the end, I get:

2014-12-12

Any ideas or leads on how to do this with Swift? Unfortunately, I can't just create an NSDate out of directly as it throws an Exception.

In the end, I want to have something like 12-12-2014 in a string format.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fortunately, You CAN just create an NSDate out of it directly as follow:

```
extension String {
    func toDateFormattedWith(format:String)-> NSDate {
        let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
//      formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 0)  // you can set GMT time 
        formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()        // or as local time
        formatter.dateFormat = format
        return formatter.dateFromString(self)!
    }
}
```

There is many ways to pick just the date from that string. I would use the following approach:

```
let myDate = "2014-12-12T14:44:18.973".componentsSeparatedByString("T")[0].toDateFormattedWith("yyyy-MM-dd") // "Dec 12, 2014, 12:00 AM"
```

You can also create an extension to extract that info from the Date object:

```
public extension NSDate {
    var day:    Int { return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitDay,    fromDate: self).day    }
    var month:  Int { return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitMonth,  fromDate: self).month  }
    var year:   Int { return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitYear,   fromDate: self).year   }

    var dateAt12am: NSDate {
        return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateWithEra(1, year: year, month: month, day: day, hour: 0, minute: 0, second: 0, nanosecond: 0)!
    }
}

let myDate1 = "2014-12-12T14:44:18.973".toDateFormattedWith("yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss.SSS").dateAt12am

println(myDate1)  // "2014-12-12 02:00:00 +0000" (12am local time)
```

If you need reference you can use this:

[image]

Comment: This is perfect, but I don't need the TIME in the final output. I just need the date. How can I go about this???

Answer (score 2):

This actually isn't too bad. What you're looking for is `rangeOfString()` to find out where "T" is. If you call `.startIndex` on that, you can find out where the first occurrence of that "T" is.

Once you have that, you can just create a substring from the beginning of the string to that point like this:

```
let date: String = dateTime.substringWithRange(Range<String.Index>(start: dateTime.startIndex, end: dateTime.rangeOfString("T")!.startIndex))
```

If you wanted to take that and turn it into an `NSDate`, you could use an `NSDateFormatter`:

```
let formatter: NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

let newDate: NSDate = formatter.dateFromString(date)! // "Dec 12, 2014, 12:00 AM"
```

If you don't want that time piece at the end and just want to output the date in a different style than that returned by the API, you could add this:

```
formatter.dateStyle = .ShortStyle // Change this to modify the style of the date that is returned in the next line
let formattedDate: String = formatter.stringFromDate(newDate) // "12/12/14"
```

Comment: This is great but I don't need the time in the final output. So how can I remove that. I've tried changing the line formatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy" or formatter.dateFormat = NSDateFormtterStyle.ShortStyle (which gives me an error). Thank you!

Comment: @MarioGuzman Ah, I see; you don't want time at all and you just want to take the extracted date from the API to output it in a different style. Try [this](https://gist.github.com/AstroCB/5d9345cbd2e242e70ff0).